# Ng-table is not filtering or sorting after getting filtered from a grouped data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am learning angular.js and new to use ng-table directive.  I am grouping my data and then showing them using ng-table. I am able to view the filtered data but I am not able to do sort or filtering. Can someone please help me with this. Here is the plunker code. Thank you!

http://plnkr.co/edit/x5NKwcxHhui9xBItqk3K?p=preview

I am using ng-table from line number 112-->

{{sample.Field1}}
          
          
                {{sample.Field4}}
          

          
            {{sample.Field5}}
          
          
            {{sample.Field6}}

          
            
            {{sample.Field7}}

          
            
            {{sample.Field8}}

          



          
            {{sample.Field9}}

in the script.js file the code

```
$scope.setCurrentSample = function(
                            options) {

                            $scope.homeview = false;
                            $scope.showdetail = false;
                            $scope.drilldown = true;

                            console.log("optionsxx = " + options.Field1);
                            $scope.myCurrentSample = _(
                                    $scope.samples).chain()
                                .where(options).value();



                            var data1 = $scope.myCurrentSample;

                            $scope['test_ngtable'] = new ngTableParams({
                                page: 1, // show first page
                                count: 10, // count per page
                                filter: {
                                    Field5: 'TRUE' // initial filter
                                },
                                sorting: {
                                    Field1: 'asc' // initial sorting
                                }
                            }, {
                                total: data1.length, // length of data
                                getData: function($defer, params) {
                                    console.log("total = " + data1.length);
                                    // use build-in angular filter
                                    var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                                        $filter('filter')(data1, params.filter()) :
                                        data1;
                                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                        data1;
                                    console.log("order by " + params.orderBy());
                                    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                                }
                            });




                        };
```

Comment: your plunk so big,can do first  : remove one row `<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">` its .duplicated, and second: can you move `ngTableParams` outside `setCurrentSample` in order to better readability and removing potential error problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="sample in myCurrentSample | filter:search ">
```

first you need to replace with this

```
 <tr ng-repeat="sample in $data | filter:search ">
```

The `ngTable` directive working with `$data` variable ,look [example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4).

### Note

i tried with your plunk ,and replacing solved the problem,[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIYZTYVnh0cGSmtk5odm?p=preview) working version of your plunk.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I ended up not using ng-table because when i replace $data it searches on entire data set, sometime not. I added function for sort and global search field to find data.

Comment: i am glad to help, `ngTable` pretty good plugin,and it can handle global search,we may figure out together if you interesting in ,by opening new question

Comment: or problem exists in current plunk?

Comment: There is a different problem in current plunk - if we click on Field 1 - it will show us 384 rows (use back button in the page) but then if we click on Field 6 - it should just show 3 rows. But it will show all rows. In my real project after some clicks the sort also stops working I could not figure out why. I will try to post new question.

Comment: oh ,i will try to solve errors in aswer's plunk a little bit later